# UV Maps Angled & Stretched Incorrectly

Tags: uv

I'm trying to make a simple crate model with a pixellated texture, but unwrapping the mesh results in an oddly distorted and angled mess of a UV map. I've already calculated that the texture needs to be 102 x 136, and the only thing stopping me from finishing is the distorted UV map. All of my transform settings are applied, and I've tried both angle-based and conformal UV mapping with both giving the exact same results, shown in the following screenshot.
[image: Distorted UV Map]
Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally very unusual to have a non-square UV map, and it's also pretty unusual to have a UV map that isn't based on powers of two. I don't know how you've come up with those numbers but you're almost certainly best off sticking to 128x128 if that's the rough size of texture you're looking at.

The non-square UV map is the reason you're having this problem, and if you really need it, there is a quick fix:

Select everything on the UV map and scale it by the ratio of the map itself. So in your case, <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, <kbd>Y</kbd> to constrain to the Y-axis, and then type 0.75 (102/136) as the amount and it will correct the distortion.